# How to get this "Spirit Light" in Inkwater Marsh

Tags: ori-and-the-will-of-wisps

There is a Spirit Light in Inkwater Marsh that I am not able to get. See images for reference.

[image: Map location]

As soon as you come near the item, the two "stones" start closing, crushing Ori in between when you try to get it.

[image: Spirit Light]

How do I get there fast enough?

Comment: Since this is a MetroidVania style game, you will likely get a "dash" type ability or upgrade so that you can come back to get this power-up later. There will be things you just cannot get in the early levels or areas and will need to return later to get them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an ability called the [Swim Dash](https://oriandtheblindforest.fandom.com/wiki/Swim_Dash) in order to obtain this spirit light. It can be gained from:

> An ancestral tree in the Luma Pools area.

If you haven't obtained this ability yet, you'll need to return later to claim your spirit light.

Comment: Thanks, I really thought I was missing something simple like a switch disabling the mechanism. I also tried bashing into the water using the projectile from the enemy above.